# java.lang.StackOverflowError when running Spring Boot app with Java 11

Tags: maven, spring-boot, slf4j, java-11

I am trying to run a simple hello world app in Spring Boot (2.1.2.RELEASE) on Java 11 (jdk-11.0.2) on Windows.  When I run the application with the Maven spring boot plugin I get the following Exception:

```
            Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:408)
                at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
                at org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory.getLogger(JCLLoggerFactory.java:77)
                at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:91)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:67)
                at org.slf4j.impl.JCLLoggerFactory.getLogger(JCLLoggerFactory.java:77)
                at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:358)
                at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jAdapter.createLocationAwareLog(LogAdapter.java:130)
```

I have the following Java code:

```
            @SpringBootApplication
            @PropertySource(value = "${url/ELMProperties}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
            @PropertySource(value = "classpath:version/elm.properties")
            //TODO remove the below line once the data source has been configured
            @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
            public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
            {
                @Override
                protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                    return application.sources(com.test.Application.class);
                }

                public static void main(String[] args)
                {
                    SpringApplication.run(com.test.Application.class, args);
                    System.out.println("Hello world");
                }
            }
```

In order exclude  by adding the following in my pom.xml file:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my maven dependency tree:

```
            [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.1:tree (default-cli) @ ep-elm-web ---
            [INFO] com.earthport.elm:ep-elm-web:war:2019.1.0-SNAPSHOT
            [INFO] +- com.earthport.security:ep-security-client:jar:2.1.0:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
            [INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
            [INFO] |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0:compile
            [INFO] +- com.earthport.shared:rabbit-support:jar:2.0.0:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.4.3:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.14.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.2:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
            [INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.7.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.1-GA:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.7:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
            [INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
            [INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
            [INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
            [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
            [INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl:jar:1.7.25:compile
            [INFO] +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:jar:3.6.2:compile
            [INFO] +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.9.1:compile
            [INFO] |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.9.1:compile
            [INFO] +- io.vavr:vavr-jackson:jar:0.9.1:compile
            [INFO] +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.0:compile
            [INFO] |  +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.5.2:compile
            [INFO] |  +- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.11:compile
            [INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP-java6:jar:2.3.13:compile
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:test
            [INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
            [INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
            [INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
            [INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
            [INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.23.4:test
            [INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.7:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
            [INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
            [INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE:test
            [INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
            [INFO] +- com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:jar:1.6.3:test
            [INFO] |  +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:test
            [INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
            [INFO] +- io.vavr:vavr-test:jar:0.9.1:test
            [INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.14:compile
            [INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.14:compile
            [INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.14:compile
            [INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.4:provided
            [INFO] +- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.2:provided
            [INFO] +- com.earthport.db2:db2jcc4:jar:4.23.42:provided
            [INFO] \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided
```

Has anyone seen a similar error like this before?  This set up has not had problems when using Java 8.

Comment: Can you post details of all your dependencies, for example the output from `mvn dependency:tree`? It looks like you have two competing implementations of the commons logging API redirecting logging to each other.

Comment: Sure have added the dependency tree to the original post.

Answer (score 8):

Your dependency on `org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl`  means that logging calls made using the SLF4J API will be passed to Commons Logging. Your dependency on `org.springframework:spring-jcl` means that calls to Commons Logging will be passed to SLF4J. This creates a cycle resulting in a stack overflow error.

Exactly how you fix the problem will depend on how you want your application to perform its logging, but you need to update your dependencies so that you have either `org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl` or `org.springframework:spring-jcl` on the classpath, and not both.

Comment: Thank you that helped.  I excluded org.slf4j:slf4j-jcl and it works.